# Проблема с подключением заголовочных файлов в VS 2017 C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, header

Есть три файла:

**Nodes.cpp**

```
#include "Token.h"
```

**Token.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "Lexer.h"
class token {
};
```

**Lexer.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "Token.h"
class Lexer
{
public:
token get_next_token();
};
```

При дебаге получаю такие ошибки :

> Ошибка C2059   синтаксическая ошибка: (
>
> Ошибка C2238   непредвиденные лексемы перед ";"
>
> Ошибка C3646   get_next_token: неизвестный спецификатор переопределения

В чем проблема?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Начинаем компилировать cpp-файл.

Включается `token.h`
Читает директиву включения `Lexer.h`
Включается `Lexer.h`
Директива включения `token.h` игнорируется благодаря `#pragma once`
Читает объявление класса `Lexer`
Сталкивается с неизвестным `token`

Еще вопросы есть?
На тот случай если есть - "что делать?" -
*В данном конкретном случае* в `Nodes.cpp` написать `#include "lexer.h"`